# show notification in android app when new article published

Tags: android, json, api, notifications, notify

i have a application that get articles from a json page on my website (like : test.com/api/v1/latest)

i want to notify the users if they didn't read the latest articles !

i saved the id of the last article that user read , then i want to get the id of the last article that published (from this page : test.com/api/v1/lastid) !

> when app is closed and not running <

then check : if the last article id in website is greater then saved id in device , then notify the user with a notification !

i want to do it every 3 or 6 hour ! how can i do that ? what is the best way to do that ?

ps1 : i should say that i don't have any problem in codding or creating a REST application , i am looking for a solution or a tip to do my job !

ps2 : i use intent service and gson to get the articles from website and i know json array !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WorkManager (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) (for a regulary scheduled task) or Firebase Cloud Messaging (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (for a push from your Server).

For the WorkManager:

Add it to your project, see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Add it to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha03"

    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version-ktx"

    // optional - Firebase JobDispatcher support
    // this makes WorkManager work better at old Android Versions -
    // it depends on your target group if you need that
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.work:work-testing:$work_version"
}
```

You will need a recent version of the support library. The version number is the target SDK version (the highest version for which it is tested), not the minimum SDK. You can still use it at older Android versions.

Then create a "Worker" to do your work and schedule it (e.g. from the MainActivity.onCreate())

```
class UpdateContentWorker: Worker() {
    companion object {
        val TAG = "UpdateContentWork"
        val enqueueLock = Object()

        fun enqueuePeriodicallyIfNotDone() {
            // Async.disk is a ThreadPool; Just use anything to run it off the UI Thread
            Async.disk.submit {
                synchronized(enqueueLock) {
                    val statuses = WorkManager.getInstance().synchronous().getStatusesByTagSync(TAG)

                    if (!scheduledOrRunning(statuses)) {
                        WorkManager.getInstance().synchronous().enqueueSync(
                                PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UpdateContentWorker>(1L, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                                        .addTag(TAG)
                                        .setConstraints(
                                                Constraints.Builder()
                                                        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                                                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                                                        .build()
                                        )
                                        .build()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun scheduledOrRunning(statuses: Collection<WorkStatus>): Boolean {
            return statuses.find {
                it.state == State.RUNNING || it.state == State.BLOCKED || it.state == State.ENQUEUED
            } != null
        }
    }

    override fun doWork(): WorkerResult {
        // do what the function title says ...

        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS
    }
}
```

Comment: i see Firebase ! this is what i want . but i want to check my server automatically not firebase . in firebase i should push notification manually ! i check work manager and let you know what i get from it ;) tnx

Comment: workmanager looks great ! but i cant find the right dependency ! :/ what should i write in gradle file ? :/

Comment: minimum sdk for workmanager is too high (Support Library 27.1) ! i want my app run in android 4.4 and higher ! :( how old apps handle such a work like this ?!

Comment: when i write : implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha02" in gradle file dependencies , it say Could not resolve ! what i miss ? what should i add to android studio ? (i don't use kotlin) @jonas-lochmann

Comment: in allprojects and buildscript i have google() and jcenter() :( what i miss ? :(
@jonas-lochmann

Comment: i should use kotlin ! that's my problem ! let me add kotlin and check again

Comment: dear @jonas-lochmann , thank you for your useful comment . post it as answer , so i close the question :) i should use kotlin in my project to use "android.arch" dependency